# How does 1-wire decide what address to use?

Tags: raspberry-pi, 1wire

I've been following this simple tutorial to get a temperature reading from a raspberrypi,
http://blog.vokiel.com/raspberry-pi-odczyt-temperatury-przez-nodejs/?lang=en

Under `w1/devices`, what I'm calling the `address` is the file where the value of the 1-wire bus is stored.

For example, the tutorial says

```
/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000249bf39 $ cat w1_slave 
c3 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 2f : crc=2f YES
c3 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 2f t=28187
```

Where the address is `28-00000249bf39`. On my device, the address is `28-000004acb882`.
How are these addresses set? Is it possible to define your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) says:

> Each Device has a Unique 64-Bit Serial Code
>   Stored in an On-Board ROM

So you can't set your own.

Answer (score -2):

To read the temperature from youre devide just type

```
cat 28.00000249bf39/temperature
```